# I have 2 user accounts on my Mac. I would like to close one account and transfer all data to the admin user before closing

Tags: macos, user-account

I have 2 user accounts on my Mac. I created the 2nd one to sort stuff properly but it's not very efficent to switch between 2 users. Therefore, I would like to close the 2nd account and transfer all data to the admin user before closing. All I want to make sure is that all the data is properly transferred before closing the 2nd account. I have both users set as administrators.

Please let me know how to do it. Thank you

I tried searching on the web to find answers but I couldn't find anything. I'm hoping asking the question here will help me and other users as well.

Comment: merging accounts isn't supported, it is possible to set up file sharing so that you can move files from one user account to the other; take a look at the resources below for how to set up and use file sharing on your Mac: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/mac